# Snowflake PUT command

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying upload to a table stage snowflake but i have seen error.

I do not see this kind of error over web

I have SF_TUTS_WH@SF_TUTS_DB.SF_TUTS_S and user as accountadmin role.

Kindly help me to fix

```
narayana#SF_TUTS_WH@SF_TUTS_DB.SF_TUTS_S>put file:///tmp/employees0*.csv @%emp_basic;
+-----------------+--------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| source          | target             | source_size | target_size | source_compression | target_compression | status | message                                                                                                                                                       |
|-----------------+--------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| employees01.csv | employees01.csv.gz |         370 |           0 | NONE               | GZIP               | ERROR  | Unknown Error in uploading a file: /tmp/tmpt4ivhu10/employees01.csv_c.gz#u6jg5p1g, file=/tmp/employees01.csv, real file=/tmp/tmpt4ivhu10/employees01.csv_c.gz |
| employees02.csv | employees02.csv.gz |         364 |           0 | NONE               | GZIP               | ERROR  | Unknown Error in uploading a file: /tmp/tmp8y9sgtpz/employees02.csv_c.gz#d_1pky9k, file=/tmp/employees02.csv, real file=/tmp/tmp8y9sgtpz/employees02.csv_c.gz |
| employees03.csv | employees03.csv.gz |         407 |           0 | NONE               | GZIP               | ERROR  | Unknown Error in uploading a file: /tmp/tmpiwbz5qg2/employees03.csv_c.gz#tyltatzq, file=/tmp/employees03.csv, real file=/tmp/tmpiwbz5qg2/employees03.csv_c.gz |
| employees04.csv | employees04.csv.gz |         375 |           0 | NONE               | GZIP               | ERROR  | Unknown Error in uploading a file: /tmp/tmp6urgqu6s/employees04.csv_c.gz#asieioee, file=/tmp/employees04.csv, real file=/tmp/tmp6urgqu6s/employees04.csv_c.gz |
| employees05.csv | employees05.csv.gz |         404 |           0 | NONE               | GZIP               | ERROR  | Unknown Error in uploading a file: /tmp/tmplk_01e71/employees05.csv_c.gz#8xsj8kmb, file=/tmp/employees05.csv, real file=/tmp/tmplk_01e71/employees05.csv_c.gz |
+-----------------+--------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
5 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 10.923s
narayana#SF_TUTS_WH@SF_TUTS_DB.SF_TUTS_S>
```

Comment: This could be a number of things, but when you say that you do not have this issue over web, what does that mean?  Are you running PUT statements from the WebUI?  Are you running SnowSQL from the same machine as the WebUI?  You may also consider opening a Support ticket, but this might be a networking issue or a client issue, which is difficult to debug with the information you've provided here.

Comment: Try to use a fully qualified namespace for the table stage

put file:///tmp/employees0*.csv @SF_TUTS_DB.SF_TUTS_S.%emp_basic;

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/getting-started-tutorial-stage-data-files.html#staging-the-files